# fopen fails in linux but works in windows

Tags: c, linux, fopen

when i run the code below it fails in linux but no problem with windows. 
filename is something like "src/folder/file"

```
char* loadProgSource(const char* filename, size_t* finalLength)
{
    char* returnStr;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(file == NULL) return NULL;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    *finalLength = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    returnStr = (char*) malloc(*finalLength+1);

    if(fread(returnStr, sizeof(char), *finalLength, file) != *finalLength) {
        fclose(file);
        free(returnStr);
        return NULL;
    }
    returnStr[*finalLength] = '\0';

    return returnStr;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the running output because it could be file path, memory leaks .. etc

Comment: Are you aware of terms like "working directory", "relative path" and "absolute path"?

Comment: You should print out errno in the case you can't open the file to get additional information

Comment: This isn't C++. I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with your code; you're going to need to tell us _where_ it fails, and what error messages occur.

Comment: At least two things are wrong: 1) `malloc()` can fail and that isn't handled! 2) `file` isn't closed in the no-error branch, hence the open file descriptor will leak.

Answer (score 1):

Not only for debugging use `perror()` in case a system command failed.

You might mod the code like so:

```
...

if (file == NULL) 
{
    perror("fopen");
    return NULL;
}

...

returnStr = malloc(*finalLength+1); /* note that casting 'malloc()' is not necessary and also not recommended uin C */
if (!returnStr)
{
  perror("malloc");
  return NULL;
}

...

if (fread(returnStr, sizeof(char), *finalLength, file) != *finalLength) 
{
  perror("fread");
  ...
```

Adding error checking on the calls to `fseek()`, `ftell()` and `fclose()` is left as an exercise.